# Cluster geojson Layer doesn't work with marker filtering

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I'm doing a Leaflet map with some GeoJSON data.

I try to add the cluster function to my JS file. As I added some filter and styling features according to properties, I'm unable to find the right way to code the cluster fonction.

Here is the GeoJSON layer and the filter verificator:

```
const geojsonLayer = L.geoJSON(null,{
filter: (feature) => {
  const isYearChecked = checkboxStates.years.includes(feature.properties.year)
  const isEventTypeChecked = checkboxStates.eventTypes.includes(feature.properties.eventType)
  return isYearChecked && isEventTypeChecked }, //only true if both are true
```

with the syling function:

```
              var year = feature.properties.year;
              if (year <= -150) {
                  return {
                      color: "black"
                  };
```

I add then the popup:

```
layer.bindPopup(popupText, {
       closeButton: true,
       offset: L.point(0, -10)
          });
     layer.on('click', function() {
       layer.openPopup();
     });
   },
}).addTo(map);
```

I try to add this piece of code to display the cluster but I don't know where to place it in my code in order to work (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster):

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addLayer(L.marker(getRandomLatLng(map)));
// ... Add more layers ...
map.addLayer(markers);
```

My whole code is available here: https://github.com/jandre3/pince-crochet

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are your features Point type? Leaflet.markercluster can only cluster point layers (Markers or CircleMarkers).

Comment: Thank you! Yes there are points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have populated your Leaflet GeoJSON Layer Group (typically with `geojsonLayer.addData(geoJsonObject)`, then instead of adding that group to your map, simply add it into your MarkerClusterGroup:

```js
const mcg = L.markerClusterGroup().addTo(map);

geojsonLayer.addData(geoJsonObject).addTo(mcg);
```

If later on you want to swap the content, you can clear it from both groups and repeat:

```js
mcg.clearLayers();
geojsonLayer.clearLayers();

geojsonLayer.addData(geoJsonObject).addTo(mcg);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hd68ea7k/

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Obviously I'm doing something wrong with it because it doesn't work by me. Is it because I use various colors of markers? May I ask you to write the code inside my example? My whole code is there (https://github.com/jandre3/pince-crochet/blob/e77d060b75b3650ea3dee79fe9e468207b8e194d/scripts/listeSites2.js)

Comment: If you can provide a reproduction example on a live editing service (e.g. as a code snippet here, or using JSFiddle, Plunkr, CodeSandbox, StackBlitz, etc.), I can try to see more specifically why it does not work in your case.

Comment: Yes, here is my code on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/titus25/x8qsbc9p/

Comment: Works as described in above answer, once you include the plugin CSS and fix the URL to the Leaflet.markercluster JS file: https://jsfiddle.net/hd68ea7k/

Comment: Many thanks for your great help !